# how to output p.value significance notation 0.1 as a "+" using tab_model in R

Tags: r, p-value

I am using Tab_model to output GEE regression results, which the default threshold is 0.5, 0.01, 0.001, and length must be 3 and all notation is "*"
I want to add 0.1 as "+", 0.5 as "*", 0.01 as "**", 0,001 as "***"
Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Are you using `sjPlot::tab_model`? https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/reference/tab_model.html

Comment: There isn't really a workaround here, the 3-element vector limit is hard-coded deep inside some non-exported helper functions of `tab_model` and you only get out formatted HTML. Your best bet might be to have this changed (or change it yourself) inside the package, or re-implement the function in its entirety..

Comment: Would that I could @PBulls, I don't have that coding skill sadly. I guess it's a waste of a bounty but thanks for your answer. Maybe some developer will see this and do it in the future :(

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, there isn't an *easy* workaround here. The 3-length limit for these thresholds and the symbols *, **, *** are hard-coded deep inside some unexported helper functions of `sjPlot::tab_model`. What's more, the return of that function is formatted HTML, so you'd have to reverse and redo the previous thresholding to make it fully flexible.

You can easily update these short helper functions, but the main function will still use the ones internal to `sjPlot`. So, my solution is to rewrite `tab_model` to use updated helpers. I'll paste that code below because it's quite long & really only changes a few lines, let's start with the result using the "More complex models" example from the vignette:

```r
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
m5 <- pscl::zeroinfl(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + ment | kid5 + phd + ment,
                     data = bioChemists)

## Custom version of sjPlot::tab_model
my_tab_model(m5, p.style = "numeric_stars",
             p.threshold = c("+"=.1, "*"=.05, "**"=.01, "***"=.001))
```

[image: tab_model HTML table]

The only real change is that `p.threshold` now accepts a **named** vector of any length, and will use the names as symbols for the thresholds. Note that there isn't any sanity checking beyond a sort implemented, so you can easily get wrong (but quite visibly so) output, for example by not providing any names or entering duplicate cut-offs.

The changes that are needed for this are:

1. a replacement of the `sjPlot:::get_p_stars` internal helper that handles arbitrary lengths + symbols, and a replacement of the footnote logic to match. I extracted the latter into a new small helper function.
2. a copy of the `sjPlot::tab_model` and `sjPlot:::format_p_values` functions that calls these helpers rather than the original code. Since these won't be part of the `sjPlot` namespace they will explicitly reference other unexported functions there. I don't think this is an issue but e.g. `R CMD CHECK` will note this.

This addresses point 1:

```r
## Replacement 'get_p_stars' function that doesn't hard-code length or symbols
my_get_p_stars <- function(pval, thresholds = NULL) {
  if (is.null(thresholds)) thresholds <- c("*"=.05, "**"=.01, "***"=.001)
  ord <- order(thresholds)
  sym <- names(thresholds)
  thresholds <- thresholds[ord]
  sym <- sym[ord]
  
  vapply(pval, \(p) {
    if (is.na(p)) return("")
    lt <- vapply(thresholds, \(t) p < t, logical(1))
    if (any(lt)) return(sym[which.max(lt)])
    return("")
  }, character(1))
}

## New function to make footnote accept arbitrary lengths & symbols
my_p_star_footnote <- function(thresholds) {
  paste(mapply(\(p, n) {
    paste0(n, " p&lt;", p)
  }, p=thresholds, n=names(thresholds)), collapse = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
}
```

Again, I stress, there's very little sanity checking here, make sure to provide *named* and ideally unique thresholds.

I cannot paste in the full code for point 2 because it's too long, you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/4LfL32Vt). It only changes a handful of lines in the original `tab_model` code to call the above helpers.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. It sent me a bunch of warning messages at one point about deprecated functions and whatnot, and it doesn't seem to like characters like † instead of + . But overall, it saves me time and it seems more intuitive to use and is in line with existing syntax of tab_model(). So I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: @SazidAhmad Those tidyverse depreciation warnings are from `sjPlot` code itself, I only used base R for the additions. At least for me it works fine when I copy the dagger into the vector name & view the table in RStudio, what issue do you get exactly? I also see now that I forgot to declare `sjPlot::css_theme` as a non-base function so you'll either have to add that package reference or attach `sjPlot` to the namespace to avoid an error.

Comment: @SazidAhmad I've updated the `my_tab_model` code behind the link to remove the `tidyselect` deprecation warnings & use `sjPlot::css_theme`. The former is technically a minor bug that will have to be fixed in the package itself also.

Answer (score 2):

As [PBulls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10781678/pbulls) says in a comment, the limit of 3 symbols is kind of "hard coded" into `sjPlot::tab_model()`.
**However**, we can accomplish this by creating a function to alter the HTML output from the function:

```r
## Helper functions
escape = function(x) gsub("([.^$*+()])", "\\\\\\1", x)
extract = function(x, p) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(p, x, perl = TRUE)))

#' Add a significance level to the output of sjPlot::tab_model()
#' 
#' @param tab Output from sjPlot::tab_model()
#' @param lvl The desired significance level to add; default = 0.1
#' @param symbol The symbol to use for that significance level; default = "+"
#' @return The altered table
add_sig_level = function(tab, lvl = 0.1, symbol = "+") {
    ## Make sure 'symbol' is escaped if need be
    metas  = c(".", "^", "$", "*", "+", "(", ")")
    symbol = escape(symbol)
    ## Extract p-values from the table
    cells = extract(tab$page.content, "(?<=col4\">).+?(?=</td>)")[-1]
    pvals = as.numeric(gsub("</*strong>|&lt;", "", cells))
    ## Find the "marginally significant ones" (i.e. 0.05 <= p < lvl)
    vars  = which(pvals >= 0.05 & pvals < lvl)
    nms   = extract(tab$page.content, "(?<=col1\">).+?(?=</td>)")[-1]
    ## Add annotations to the appropriate rows
    for ( j in vars ) {
        jj  = escape(nms[j])
        pat = paste0("(col1\">", jj, "(.|\n)+?col2\">.+?<sup>)</sup>")
        entry = paste0("\\1", symbol, "</sup>")
        tab$page.content = gsub(pat, entry, tab$page.content, perl = TRUE)
        tab$page.complete = gsub(pat, entry, tab$page.complete, perl = TRUE)
    }
    ## Add the new symbol to the table footnote
    pat = "footnote\">"
    replacement = paste0(pat, symbol, " p&lt;", lvl, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
    tab$page.content = gsub(pat, replacement, tab$page.content)
    tab$page.complete = gsub(pat, replacement, tab$page.complete)
    ## Return result
    return(tab)
}
```

To illustrate, I created an example dataset and model with two predictors that would be significant at the 0.1 level but not the 0.05 level:

```r
## Simulate example data
set.seed(138)
n = 30
X = cbind(rnorm(n), rnorm(n), rnorm(n))
b = c(1, 1, 0.4, 0.4)
y = c(cbind(1, X) %*% b + rnorm(n))

## Fit the model
example_model = lm(y ~ X)
model_summary = summary(example_model)
model_summary
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5577 -0.5564 -0.1403  0.5669  1.6760 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.9253     0.1710   5.410 1.14e-05 ***
X1            1.0339     0.1648   6.274 1.22e-06 ***
X2            0.3097     0.1754   1.766   0.0891 .  
X3            0.2693     0.1394   1.933   0.0642 .  
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8775 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.617, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5728 
F-statistic: 13.96 on 3 and 26 DF,  p-value: 1.281e-05
```

Here's the initial output of `sjPlot::tab_model()`:

```r
tab = sjPlot::tab_model(example_model, p.style = "numeric_stars")
tab
```

[image]

Now here's the output from our new function:

```r
add_sig_level(tab)
```

[image]

**Success**! We can see that `X2` and `X3` are marked with the `+` symbol,
and that symbol's meaning is explained in the table's footnote.
Here's an illustration that we can use any custom significance level with the way the function was constructed; if we use `lvl = 0.08`, then `X3` should still pop with the `+` symbol but `X2` should not (since its p-value is 0.089):

```r
add_sig_level(tab, example_model, lvl = 0.08)
```

[image]

And the annotations and the table's footnote are as expected.

### Update: non-`lm` objects

PBulls correctly pointed out that my original approach would not handle all types of models well.
The updated version presented in this answer does not depend on the model object at all, only the output from `sjPlots::tab_model()`.
To illustrate, here's how it works on the model from PBulls' answer:

```r
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
m5 <- pscl::zeroinfl(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + ment | kid5 + phd + ment,
                     data = bioChemists)

add_sig_level(sjPlot::tab_model(m5, p.style = "numeric_stars"))
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly works, but relies on quite a few assumptions (e.g. the way *P*-values are extracted from the `model` object probably won't work for much more than `lm` output & the way variables are located within the HTML table -- these can be renamed/relabeled by `tab_model`). Anyway, shows me right that I couldn't just write a post-processing helper :-)

Comment: @PBulls Yeah, I was just noticing that myself, though I think I have a work-around for it that I'll post a bit later

Comment: @PBulls see my edit; still surely not perfectly general, but should be much closer to general

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the package `gtsummary`. You can modify footnotes and p-value significance stars for your table. I use `tbl_regression` to build the base table from the model and add significance starts to the table. The default is to only use stars but with a few functions we can change the * to any symbols you want. You can also change the thresholds as well but I just made a few for illustration.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(glmmTMB)
zinbm2 = glmmTMB(count~spp + mined +(1|site), zi=~spp + mined + (1|site),, family=nbinom2)

data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
m5 <- glmmTMB(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 , zi = ~ kid5 + phd,
                     data = bioChemists,family=nbinom2)

t1 <- gtsummary::tbl_regression(m5) %>% 
  add_significance_stars(thresholds = c(.001,.01,.05,.15),
                         pattern = "{p.value}{stars}",
                         hide_p = FALSE)

t1 %>% 
  modify_table_body(~.x %>% 
                      mutate(stars = ifelse(stars == "","",
                                     ifelse(stars == "*","+",
                                     ifelse(stars == "**","**","***"))))) %>% 
  modify_footnote(p.value ~ "+p<0.15; *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<0.001")
```